# ServiceStack Profile Steps not rendering

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a ServiceStack Service with a service call like so:

```
    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public object Get(MyServiceRequest request)
        {
            using (Profiler.Current.Step("Getting Data"))
            {
                // code that gets data

                using (Profiler.Current.Step("Doing work with data"))
                {
                    // code that does work
                }
            }
            return response;
        }           
    }
```

and a global.asax.cs like so:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
            Profiler.Start();
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Profiler.Stop();
    }       
}
```

My problem is that when I test the service call through the browser I only see profile information for the overall request.  "show time with children" and "show trivial" don't provider any more granular information.  I've also placed breakpoints within each `using` statement to get a look at `Profiler.Current` and noticed in each case its `Children` property is null.  Am I doing it wrong?  Are they any other things I can do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is your Service being called via AJAX request? If you do Ctrl-F5 on the page in the browser do you get more granular information?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason setting the `level` argument to `Profile.Info` in the `Step` method resolves my issue. That's weird because `Profile.Info` is the default if no argument is provided.  Oh well.  Moving on.